# Users get flooded with messages about connection problems

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

We have an installation with TYPO3 8.7.45

since half a year the editors get flash messages with the text:

> Connection Problem
>
> Sorry, but an error occurred while connecting to the server. Please
> check your network connection.

That is independent from current activity, also it seems to be triggered more often when they are editing CEs.

with my admin-account I have no problems, if I change user and `su` to an editor account I also get the messages:
just open a CE and wait. about 1 minute later the users get flooded with about 40 Flash messages.

In the TYPO3 log there are no entries for the editor or my account for the moment the messages appear.
In the apache log no error occurs.

In the moment of the messages a JSon call comes back but with http-code 200.
it went to `https://<mydomain.tld>/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=/ajax/usersettings/process&ajaxToken=5fbc9e1b13fae602644589e9ec63ffadb72b35d9`

in the returned JSON nothing special about errors.
It looks like a user record from a system with a lot of pages, so there are lot of page-tree states and fileadmin-tree states:
(*I needed to shorten it (marked `[...]`) because questions aren't allowed to have so much characters.*)

```js
{"interfaceSetup":"","moduleData":{"web_layout":{"function":"1","language":"0","tx_news_domain_model_news":"0","tt_content_showHidden":"1"},"file_list":{"displayThumbs":"0","clipBoard":"1","sort":"tstamp","reverse":"1","bigControlPanel":"1"},"xMOD_alt_doc.php":{"showPalettes":"1"},"browse_links.php":{"expandFolder":"1:\/Amt13\/pressebilder\/2203\/"},"TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Utility\\BackendUtility::getUpdateSignal":[],"alt_doc.php":[{"660b4939a8bf42a082f905afb03f4516":["Kontakt: Anschrift und \u00d6ffnungszeiten",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"106675":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"disHelp":null,"noView":null,"editRegularContentFromId":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][106675]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&disHelp=&noView=&editRegularContentFromId=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":"106675","pid":"25118746","cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":1}],"822cbb912270bea67ed3d23f6971d695":["kontakt",{"edit":{"pages":{"25118746":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"disHelp":null,"noView":null,"editRegularContentFromId":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][25118746]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&disHelp=&noView=&editRegularContentFromId=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":"25118746","pid":"602608","cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":1}],"9c9482943997a2a98c5020403aa15134":["leitbild",{"edit":{"pages":{"700019831":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"disHelp":null,"noView":null,"editRegularContentFromId":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][700019831]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&disHelp=&noView=&editRegularContentFromId=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":"700019831","pid":"612936","cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":1}],"f1ef5e93a1cf3b8797aa0a3d5344e0c3":["Bisher wurden folgende Angebote freigegeben",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"105443":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"disHelp":null,"noView":null,"editRegularContentFromId":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][105443]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&disHelp=&noView=&editRegularContentFromId=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":"105443","pid":"700019562","cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":1}]},"f1ef5e93a1cf3b8797aa0a3d5344e0c3"],"opendocs::recent":{"9a4e39ea0ed9c3e36d610032f3759b04":["<em>[No title]<\/em>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"158874":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][158874]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":158874,"pid":700029703,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"20b2b58f966003a498f53fb6419dbd98":["Aktuelle Zahlen",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"158839":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][158839]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":158839,"pid":1,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"eda3aceebdc3b0db5e88cc4420f7e307":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"pages":{"700029699":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][700029699]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":700029699,"pid":700022451,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"c6aa2d6ea12a6222496fa25bec9e6e51":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"pages":{"700029700":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][700029700]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":700029700,"pid":700022451,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"5228a4f43e5763f697b319eb4626bda6":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"pages":{"700029701":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][700029701]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":700029701,"pid":700022451,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"d950f407a31b31cf430a78f477be31ab":["<span title=\"LIVE-\u00dcbertragung der Ratssitzung (Einblendung mit Geb\u00e4rdensprache)\">LIVE-\u00dcbertragung der Ratssitzung (Einblendung mit ...<\/span>",{"edit":{"pages":{"700022156":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[pages][700022156]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"pages","uid":700022156,"pid":47566584,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"23f2700a5c1055c33622b8d5bd73c0ba":["<span title=\"Rat LIVE (ohne Geb\u00e4rden) --&gt; DATUM\/UHRZEIT EDITIEREN!\">Rat LIVE (ohne Geb\u00e4rden) --&gt; DATUM\/UHRZEIT EDITIER...<\/span>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"117768":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][117768]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":117768,"pid":47566584,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"ada52d1c5cee2005440c68ec4250ed39":["<span title=\"Bitte beachten Sie, dass im Vorfeld der Ratssitzung ab etwa 12 Uhr an dieser Stelle auch die Sondersitzung des APS \u00fcbertragen wird\">Bitte beachten Sie, dass im Vorfeld der Ratssitzun...<\/span>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"150931":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][150931]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":150931,"pid":47566584,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}]},"web_list":{"bigControlPanel":"1","clipBoard":"1"},"clipboard":{"tab_1":[],"tab_2":[],"tab_3":[],"current":"normal","normal":{"el":{"pages|700029114":"1"},"mode":"copy"}},"web_txrecyclerM1":{"function":""},"Workspaces":{"1":{"columns":{"uid":{"position":2,"hidden":1},"t3ver_oid":{"position":3,"hidden":1},"workspace_Title":{"position":4,"hidden":1},"path_Workspace":{"position":5,"hidden":1},"path_Live":{"position":6,"hidden":1},"label_Workspace":{"position":7,"hidden":0},"":{"position":13,"hidden":0},"label_Live":{"position":9,"hidden":0},"workspace_Tstamp":{"position":10,"hidden":1},"label_Stage":{"position":11,"hidden":0},"languageValue":{"position":14,"hidden":0}}},"States":{"WorkspacePreviewModeSelect":{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"stdClass","viewMode":0}}},"web_func":{"function":"TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardCrpages\\Controller\\CreatePagesWizardModuleFunctionController","wiz":"TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardCrpages\\Controller\\CreatePagesWizardModuleFunctionController","cr_333":"0"},"FormEngine":[{"9a4e39ea0ed9c3e36d610032f3759b04":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"158874":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][158874]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":158874,"pid":700029703,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"d93f233ed25df73034534ee3e0ab2698":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"158880":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][158880]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":158880,"pid":700029703,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}],"6187130f59b81617a4b5d4e163fd5260":["<em>[Kein Titel]<\/em>",{"edit":{"tt_content":{"158878":"edit"}},"defVals":null,"overrideVals":null,"columnsOnly":null,"noView":null,"workspace":null},"&edit[tt_content][158878]=edit&defVals=&overrideVals=&columnsOnly=&noView=&workspace=",{"table":"tt_content","uid":158878,"pid":700029703,"cmd":"edit","deleteAccess":true}]},"6187130f59b81617a4b5d4e163fd5260"],"list":{"sys_category":"1"}},"thumbnailsByDefault":1,"emailMeAtLogin":0,"noMenuMode":0,"startModule":"help_AboutAboutmodules","hideSubmoduleIcons":0,"helpText":1,"titleLen":"50","edit_showFieldHelp":"icon","edit_RTE":1,"edit_docModuleUpload":1,"navFrameWidth":"","navFrameResizable":0,"resizeTextareas":1,"resizeTextareas_MaxHeight":"500","resizeTextareas_Flexible":1,"lang":"de","firstLoginTimeStamp":1447077676,"moduleSessionID":{"web_layout":"970e8320299dff8141a8ae5550248e95","file_list":"e8540991962ffea48972579b039fe76ff021a642","xMOD_alt_doc.php":"2348125aac375ac7fcb481b4e72dd1a8","browse_links.php":"de32bac4e63a360cd9d20bb2fa66269fa66ee1a1","TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Utility\\BackendUtility::getUpdateSignal":"4bd1d5f1dfc072847f05eb4589559d0c7f253fd7","alt_doc.php":"3f597fbbc55cd7d85b374d2e42fbdf27","opendocs::recent":"f8a789d8ba37bfb4092ed3097ccfe657b60d1de0","web_list":"e4a4206a8c2ad2709558d7ff46c9292b","clipboard":"04dc9fc58ff24077fabce794c074cdaf1d3f249e","web_txrecyclerM1":"64095ed83622655296a1eb61fa11f6f1","web_func":"e4a4206a8c2ad2709558d7ff46c9292b","FormEngine":"4bd1d5f1dfc072847f05eb4589559d0c7f253fd7"},"BackendComponents":{"States":{"Pagetree":{"stateHash":{"0":"1","1":"1","8":"1","42989":"1","2398536":"1","3396226":"1","root":"1","lastSelectedNode":"p29b99b07-1","7d-1":"1","0-1":"1","109db":"1","5a":"1","5952a-1":"1","2176632-1":"1","596d3-1":"1","1bfe20d-1":"1","197a39e-1":"1","596a6-1":"1","5952a":"1","133-1":"1","10a37-1":"1","24dcf1-1":"1","10b4a-1":"1","10b3d-1":"1","10b31-1":"1","10b18-1":"1","10b0f-1":"1","10b00-1":"1","10af1-1":"1","10ae2-1":"1","10aca-1":"1","10abb-1":"1","10ab0-1":"1","10aa5-1":"1","10ad7-1":"1","10a9a-1":"1","10a8d-1":"1","10a82-1":"1","10a77-1":"1","10a6a-1":"1","5ca6e-1":"1","10a5f-1":"1","10a54-1":"1","f-1":"1","44-1":"1","18f8fc9-1":"1","578955-1":"1","f1a059-1":"1","e30836-1":"1","dea08d-1":"1","208311d-1":"1","16c1eb5-1":"1","e4f728-1":"1","199d5e0-1":"1","bb3299-1":"1","1355-1":"1","51-1":"1","1356-1":"1","5c-1":"1","59-1":"1","5d-1":"1","29b92777-1":"1","29b92778-1":"1","15ed719-1":"1","131d3f5-1":"1","131d4a6-1":"1","131d4b5-1":"1","131b2d3-1":"1","131d528-1":"1","1409373-1":"1","1359-1":"1","1358-1":"1","60-1":"1","d5a715-1":"1","d5af81-1":"1","d5e5c7-1":"1","d5e131-1":"1","d5a7b6-1":"1","d5ee4c-1":"1","d5a782-1":"1","d5ac3f-1":"1","d5ced2-1":"1","d5a741-1":"1","bc-1":"1","1353-1":"1","130-1":"1","1469-1":"1","1477-1":"1","1474-1":"1","1467-1":"1","146a-1":"1","145f-1":"1","145e-1":"1","1463-1":"1","a":"1","2bf6dfd-1":"1","14b81b6-1":"1","9cbda-1":"1","10956da-1":"1","211c77c-1":"1","252794e-1":"1","27b1d9c-1":"1","36ea080-1":"1","3ac89ca-1":"1","22e6e52-1":"1","43eec-1":"1","43e82-1":"1","194725-1":"1","22e675b-1":"1","6b7b65-1":"1","123ec90-1":"1","cc872b-1":"1","29b9277d-1":"1","2e52606-1":"1","2e52611-1":"1","2e67188-1":"1","15c23e4-1":"1","a4f195-1":"1","a4f39c-1":"1","ab8906-1":"1","9fa22b-1":"1","2e5261c-1":"1","2e52627-1":"1","2e67212-1":"1","501b2-1":"1","501a0-1":"1","5018e-1":"1","5017c-1":"1","51189-1":"1","5014f-1":"1","5013d-1":"1","5012b-1":"1","5011b-1":"1","5010b-1":"1",
[...]
"29b998c5-1":"1","29b99961-1":"1","29b99b07-1":"1","29b98781-1":"1"}},"typo3-debug-console":{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"stdClass","collapsed":true},"typo3-navigationContainer":{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"stdClass","width":296},"typo3-module-menu":{"collapsed":"false"}}},"inlineView":"a:4:{i:0;b:0;s:10:\"tt_content\";a:187:{s:26:\"NEW564485584a92e5.98221160\";a:1:{s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:2781;}}s:26:\"NEW56448854b867f2.94486646\";a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:2:{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:17;}}i:3906;a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"17\";}}i:3904;a:1:{s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:2782;}}s:26:\"NEW564497679aaa89.38502072\";a:1:{s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:2783;}}s:26:\"NEW5644990587f6c0.43562791\";a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:3:{i:0;i:18;i:1;i:19;i:2;i:20;}}i:3909;a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:1:{i:2;s:2:\"20\";}}s:26:\"NEW564499e943e1f1.95784363\";a:1:{s:35:\"tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_links\";a:1:{i:0;i:19;}}i:3910;a:2:{s:35:\"tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_links\";a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"19\";}s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:2784;}}i:3914;a:1:{s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:2785;}}s:26:\"NEW56459a04be3676.35373215\";a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:3:{i:0;i:21;i:1;i:22;i:2;i:23;}}i:3923;a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:2:{i:0;s:2:\"21\";i:1;i:24;}}s:26:\"NEW5666ad3622fa02.50202619\";a:1:{s:38:\"tx_lhdaccordion_domain_model_accordion\";a:2:{i:0;i:132;i:1;i:133;}}i:59980;a:2:{s:38:\"tx_lhdaccordion_domain_model_accordion\";a:3:{i:0;i:135;i:1;i:136;i:2;s:3:\"132\";}s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:12903;}}s:26:\"NEW5666aeb9550a79.88897578\";a:1:{s:35:\"tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_links\";a:4:{i:0;i:162;i:1;i:163;i:2;i:164;i:3;i:165;}}i:59987;a:2:{s:35:\"tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_links\";a:1:{i:0;s:3:\"165\";}s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:1:{i:0;i:12899;}}s:26:\"NEW5666af96203395.43370281\";a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:2:{i:0;i:52;i:1;i:53;}}i:59988;a:1:{s:38:\"tx_addresscontact_domain_model_entries\";a:4:{i:0;s:2:\"52\";i:1;s:2:\"53\";i:2;i:54;i:3;i:55;}}
[...]
{i:37;a:2:{s:18:\"sys_file_reference\";a:31:{i:0;i:965980;i:1;s:5:\"78558\";i:2;s:6:\"873652\";i:3;s:6:\"873649\";i:4;s:6:\"873650\";i:5;s:5:\"78559\";i:6;i:966011;i:7;i:966012;i:8;i:966013;i:9;i:966014;i:10;i:966015;i:11;s:5:\"78566\";i:12;s:5:\"78567\";i:13;s:5:\"92667\";i:14;s:5:\"92668\";i:15;s:6:\"136503\";i:16;s:6:\"136504\";i:17;s:6:\"873653\";i:18;s:6:\"873654\";i:19;i:966020;i:20;i:966021;i:21;i:966022;i:22;i:966023;i:23;i:966024;i:24;i:966025;i:25;i:966026;i:26;i:966027;i:27;i:966032;i:28;i:966033;i:29;i:966034;i:30;i:966035;}s:34:\"tx_topdownloads_domain_model_files\";a:2:{i:0;i:54;i:1;i:55;}}}}","browseTrees":{"browsePages":"a:2:{i:0;a:10:{i:1;i:1;i:90;i:1;i:68059;i:1;i:365866;i:1;i:272777;i:1;i:48557936;i:1;i:10809630;i:1;i:8;i:1;i:646999;i:1;i:700020828;i:1;}i:1;a:3:{i:8;i:1;i:10;i:1;i:1;i:1;}}","folder":"a:32:[...]
i:12376;a:2:{i:30582462;i:1;i:149293772;i:1;}}"},"tx_recycler":{"tableSelection":"pages","depthSelection":999,"resultLimit":25},"tcaTrees":{"d2e1133f7858a3957716afd25af53d72":"19,16,9,8,10,20,23,14,13,15,12,11,17,7,6,5,4,3,1,2,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,0,94,540,77,554,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,95,96,97,98,652,650,651,99,620,103,104,105,106,107,108,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,123,126,128,646,644,642,638,636,539,659,657,653,583,564,626,555,567,124,648,614,579,575,573,571,569,612,599,601,611,610,592,613,598,609,596,608,594,589,591,593,597,602,605,552,600,604,607,127,668,665,663,661,670,679,681,677,675,673,727,725,723,689,687,699,697,691,720,715,713,711,709,707,704,683,749,741,733,731","56cc2cb74973d6f0ea9e9acbe15d6740":"94,540,57,77,554,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,105,106,107,108,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,123,128,23,539,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,583,37,38,39,41,43,44,45,46,48,52,53,54,55,56,564,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,555,69,74,567,124,579,575,573,571,569,27,599,601,598,596,592,594,591,593,597,7,607,9,12,589,24,603,602,605,600,604,16,552,127,0","a7d15c754468b5fc94c2c53b71143f5e":"94,540,57,77,554,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,105,106,107,108,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,123,128,23,539,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,583,37,38,39,41,43,44,45,46,48,52,53,54,55,56,564,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,555,69,74,567,124,579,575,573,571,569,27,599,601,598,596,592,594,591,593,597,607,9,12,589,24,603,602,16,605,552,600,604,127,0,612,611,610,613,609,608","443d80474938692cad9b4e38aa269105":",0,24,127,94,540,57,77,554,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,105,106,107,108,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,123,128,23,539,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,583,37,38,39,41,43,44,45,46,48,52,53,54,55,56,564,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,555,69,74,567,124,579,575,573,571,569,27,612,599,601,611,610,592,613,598,609,596,608,594,12,589,591,593,597,602,605,552,600,604,607"},"modulemenu":"{}","TSFE_adminConfig":{"DUMMY":"","display_top":"0","display_preview":"1","display_edit":"0","display_info":"1","preview_showHiddenPages":"1","preview_showHiddenRecords":"0","preview_showFluidDebug":"0","preview_simulateDate":"1649332800","display_cache":"0","display_tsdebug":"0"},"realName":"","email":"","password":"","password2":"","passwordCurrent":"","avatar":"","showHiddenFilesAndFolders":0,"copyLevels":"","recursiveDelete":0,"resetConfiguration":""}
```

**How can I get more Information what connection has the problems?**

Comment: We had that often in large pagetrees where the editors had expanded (too) many subtrees. For editors, there are several queries checking permissions. This can be too much for the database server (or the configures max connections). As an admin, many of these checks do not happen - because you are admin ;)

Comment: can that be fixed with an increased number of DB-connections?

Comment: It depends... In our case, we had editors having expanded the pagetree over 20 screen-heights... In such a case, editors have to learn closing subtrees or - even better - using "Mount as treeroot" while working in a certain area of the page.

Comment: Maybe https://packagist.org/packages/ichhabrecht/begroups-roles can help reduce the pages/records by switching to the appropriate role.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a serverside firewall is responsible for that. and blocks the suspischouls looking traffic

Comment: firewall and proxy are involved, but there is no request which does not get fulfilled (HTTP return other than 200). At least that's what the browser(FF) console tells me. Thou there seems to be no blocking.